# WCF - HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

My first post on Stackoverflow!

I am having some problems with a WCF service I am trying to build and I need some help in trying to figure it out.

There are two parts to the service, the first is a very simple REST style web service full of GET methods, this works fine.

The next area is a Pub/Sub model which basically will push out to subscribers internally the results of a particular invoke method from the first area. To incorporate this I am listening on two endpoints, now every time I invoke one method on the PubSub service I get the error above. After searching the interwebulator I have seen a lot of posts saying that IIS is using port 80 by default.

Now two questions:
 1. My service is listening on the following base address, nothing to do with 80
http://localhost:3526/TradePortal and http://localhost:3526/TradePortal/Operations
 2. I would ideally host this in IIS

The suggestion is I change the client base address to not use port 80, but is that set on the sever side or the client side config.

I'm a bit puzzled as to the solution to this, I have previously built a pubsub model using NetTCP as the binding.

Any clues as to how to solve this would be appreciated

Server side config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="CFP_Web_Lib.TradePortal">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3526/TradePortal"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                 contract="CFP_Web_Lib.ITradePortal"
                      behaviorConfiguration="web"
                 />
          <endpoint address="Operations/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
               contract="CFP_Web_Lib.ITradeOperations"/>
               </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client side code (auto generated by VS2010)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_ITradeOperations" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3526/TradePortal/Operations/"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ITradeOperations"
            contract="CFP_Web.ITradeOperations" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ITradeOperations">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="callison@cfpartners.local" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is client not server. `WsDualHttpBinding` uses two connections - one from client to server and one from server to client (to support callbacks). That is reason why it is called dual. To allow incomming connection client exposes its own server (callback implementation) under the hood. This service also must have some address and unused port. If you do not specify this address it will by default use port 80 which is most probably already in use by IIS. You must change this address on client side. Use `clientBaseAddress` attribute of binding configuration.